# How to make toJSON wait for find before returning the object in Sails.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I'm running a find inside the following toJSON in the model but it return returns the object before the find completes. How can I wait until the find completes before firing the return?

```
toJSON: function() {
 var obj = this.toObject();
 Comment.find({
    postID: obj.id
 }).limit(2).sort('createdAt DESC').exec(function(err, comments) {
    obj.comments = comments; //this is not reflected in return obj
    if (obj.isTrue) {
        //yes
    } else {
        //no
    }
});
return obj; // obj.comments not reflected :(
}
```

The goal is for `obj.comments` to be in `obj` when it is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to add an associate between posts and comments.

You can find documentation on that here: http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/Associations

For example, in the post model add an attribute like so

```
comments: {
  collection: 'comment',
  via: 'postID'
},
```

And in the comments model add this attribute

```
postId: {
  model: 'hacks',
  type: 'STRING',
  required: true
},
```

when adding new documents set a comment's postId to the id of the post you'd like to associate.
Then in the post controller when you are finding posts add populate like so

```
.populate('comments', {
  limit: 3,
  sort: 'createdAt DESC'
}).exec(...
```